# Is roll rate forecasting model the same as ARIMA

Tags: excel, statistics, finance, quantitative-finance, banking

I am currently trying to build a roll rate model to estimate financial losses over the next few months. I was recently made aware of ARIMA models, and I wanted to know if a roll rate model was intrinsically auto-regressive or moving average? I have not been able to find this information online. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about finance but it does not appear to be auto-regression based as per random link I googled https://www.orchardplatform.com/blog/roll-rate-analysis-estimating-value-pool-loans/ and this http://dni-institute.in/blogs/loss-forecasting-model-overview-and-definitions/  That said, this currently isn't really on topic for SO ,

Comment: It appears there are different models (e.g. Markov chain). Quoting [this](http://www.strategicanalytics.com/pdf/RMAJ200310ForecastTools.pdf) p6: ..Roll Rates The classic roll-rate model is a structural model of the net rate at which accounts roll through delinquency buckets. (See Figure 6.) Predictions are made by computing a moving average of historical
roll rates.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is on topic but It appears there are different models (e.g. Markov chain). Quoting [this](http://www.strategicanalytics.com/pdf/RMAJ200310ForecastTools.pdf) p6: ..Roll Rates The classic roll-rate model is a structural model of the net rate at which accounts roll through delinquency buckets. (See Figure 6.) Predictions are made by computing a **moving average** of historical roll rates. So, no, they are not the same.